# Traefik + cloudflared with full strict tunnel on docker

Tags: docker, cloudflare, traefik

I have a VM which run multiple containers all linked to one docker network.

- Traefik (as reverse proxy & load balancer)
- cloudflared as tunnel
- whoami (for testing purposes)
- and some containers like photoprism, nextcloud, node-red,...

I generated an origin cert via Cloudflare which has been added to Traefik.
In Cloudflare, I have a subdomain which points via the tunnel to [https://172.16.10.11](https://172.16.10.11/) (ip from the VM). This causes an unsecure connection (IP SAN applied -> I don't think this is possible on a private ip?). When I disable TLS verification on Cloudflare, it works. However, I am trying to set this up properly. Next,I tried pointing my domain towards [https://localhost](https://localhost/). the cloudflared service running in a container cannot reach any other services as these are located other containers.

I was thinking, what if I run the cloudflared service within the Traefik container, I believe I can reach Traefik via localhost?

Do you have any advice on how to achieve a secure tunnel with cert verification? Or is this not realistic when self-hosting?

Current docker compose:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    command: 
      - --log.level=debug
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --serverstransport.insecureskipverify
      - --providers.file.filename=/etc/traefik/dynamic_conf.yml
      - --providers.file.watch=true
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "443:443"
      - "80:80"
    networks: 
      - proxy_network
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - traefik-data:/etc/traefik
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network=proxy_network
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`${DOMAINNAME_TRAEFIK}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=traefik
      - traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
  tunnel:
    container_name: cloudflared-tunnel
    image: cloudflare/cloudflared
    #restart: unless-stopped
    networks: 
      - proxy_network
    command: tunnel --no-autoupdate run --token ${CLOUDFLARED_TOKEN}
  whoami:
    image: traefik/whoami
    container_name: whoami1
    command:
       # It tells whoami to start listening on 2001 instead of 80
       - --port=2000
       - --name=iamfoo
    networks: 
      - proxy_network
    labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`${DOMAINNAME}`)
        - traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=websecure
        - traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls=true
        - traefik.http.routers.whoami.service=whoami
        - traefik.http.services.whoami.loadbalancer.server.port=2000
volumes:  
  traefik-data:
    driver: local
networks:
  proxy_network:
    name: proxy_network
    external: true
```

I expect a secure tunnel solution and to make sure that this architecture is setup in a good way.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a subdomain which points via the tunnel to https://172.16.10.11
> (ip from the VM). This causes an unsecure connection (IP SAN applied
> -> I don't think this is possible on a private ip?). When I disable TLS verification on Cloudflare, it works.

While I'm not absolutely sure what you're trying to say here, I'm assuming you're not able to establish a secure connection to Traefik via cloudflared. This is most likely due to the fact that you did not specify the host header in Cloudflare Zero Trust > Access > Tunnels > *your-tunnel-name* > Public Hostname > *your-hostname* > Edit > Additional application settings > HTTP Settings > HTTP Host Header, therefore Traefik is unable to match the correct TLS certificate to use for the request.

> Next,I tried pointing my domain towards https://localhost. the
> cloudflared service running in a container cannot reach any other
> services as these are located other containers.
>
> I was thinking, what if I run the cloudflared service within the
> Traefik container, I believe I can reach Traefik via localhost?

localhost = 127.0.0.1. It will not work in a container setup without using host mode. You should use `traefik` as the backend location.

> Do you have any advice on how to achieve a secure tunnel with cert
> verification? Or is this not realistic when self-hosting?

Frankly it's both cumbersome and unnecessary to implement "cert verification" here, if you're indicating that Traefik and cloudflared should connect using TLS. It introduces more overhead when connecting to the actual backend, and there's really *not much* point in doing TLS here -- the internal Docker bridge network is only accessible to those containers in the same network, and the applications running on the Docker host machine here. Cloudflare Tunnel already introduces a secure connection to the Cloudflare Edges.

I'm suggesting that you use insecure entrypoint for Traefik, that is, plain HTTP, and use HTTP as backend in Cloudflare Zero Trust (i.e.: http://traefik), and this will do.